# Can't download file from java servlet using php

Tags: php, file, servlets, curl

So I'm struggling with the code below.  I have java that is serving a file and php that is trying to grab the file and save it.  I can download the file from the servlet just fine in a browser.  I can download any file or webpage (SSL or not) with the php code.  But FOR THE LIFE OF ME i cant get the php to download from this servlet!!!  Im pretty familiar with PHP but not so much with java and i didnt write that servlet if it helps.  I can however edit either end of the code.  Thank you!!

JAVA:

```
@Override
public void doGet( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        String fileName = "/tmp/DongleUpdate.jar";
        File f = new File( "/tmp/DongleUpdate.jar" );
        response.setContentType( "application/zip" );
        response.setHeader( "Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" +
                fileName + "\"" );
        byte[] arBytes = new byte[( int ) f.length()];
        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream( f );
        is.read( arBytes );
        ServletOutputStream op = response.getOutputStream();
        op.write( arBytes );
        op.flush();

    } catch( IOException ioe ) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

PHP:

```
$ch = curl_init($file);
curl_setopt($ch, CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_GET, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
curl_setopt($cURL,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array(
    "Accept: application/zip"
));
$rawdata=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

$fp = fopen($saveloc,'w');
fwrite($fp, $rawdata);
fclose($fp);
```

I've tried every version of curl options i can think of here.  I'm new to stack overflow but i can message someone the actual link im using if it helps.  Also if it helps here's a raw connection output to the link from fiddler:

```
CONNECT XXXX:8443 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0
Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive
Host: XXXX

A SSLv3-compatible ClientHello handshake was found. Fiddler extracted the parameters below.

Version: 3.1 (TLS/1.0)
Random: XXXX
SessionID: empty
Extensions: 
elliptic_curves XXXX
ec_point_formats    01 00
SessionTicket TLS   empty
NextProtocolNegotiation empty
Ciphers: 
[00FF]  TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV
[C00A]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
[C014]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
[0088]  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA
[0087]  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA
[0039]  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA
[0038]  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_SHA
[C00F]  TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
[C005]  TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
[0084]  TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA
[0035]  TLS_RSA_AES_256_SHA
[C007]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
[C009]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
[C011]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
[C013]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
[0045]  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA
[0044]  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA
[0033]  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA
[0032]  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_SHA
[C00C]  TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
[C00E]  TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
[C002]  TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
[C004]  TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
[0096]  TLS_RSA_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA
[0041]  TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA
[0005]  SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
[0004]  SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
[002F]  TLS_RSA_AES_128_SHA
[C008]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
[C012]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
[0016]  SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_SHA
[0013]  SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_SHA
[C00D]  TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
[C003]  TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
[FEFF]  SSL_RSA_FIPS_WITH_3DES_EDE_SHA
[000A]  SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_SHA
```

Compression: 
    [00]    NO_COMPRESSION

Comment: you are attempting httpS?

Answer (score 0):

Old post but if anyone cares im just an idiot and did a cut and paste blunder so my curl options have two different variables labeled :/

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you'd have better luck if the Java side set the `Content-length` header.

Browsers can usually do without it, but here ... ?

Comment: Attempted SSL and non-SSL.  Also added content length with no luck :/

Comment: Do i need to do anything funky or have my hosting company open outbound port 8443 for this?  I just checked and outbound 8443 is blocked....

Comment: When content length is not set, servlet defaults to chunked encoding. This is supported by all decent HTTP clients. By the way, if the encoding wasn't chunked, most browsers wouldn't eat that either.